# Get alert response from external site

Tags: php, ajax, curl, get, scrape

I'm trying ot figure out away to get a response from this website: 
https://www.primarycare.nhs.uk/publicfn/catchment.aspx?oc=P91012&h=600&w=800&if=0

oc=P91012 - this is the practice identifier.

We then have a postcode field where a user checks if they are in the catchment area

The site issues a javascript alert to inform the user if they are / or not in the catchment area.

Is it possible to send a PHP Curl request that sends a postcode to this website and checks whether or not the postcode is in the catchment area and send a reponse back to my site?

```
<?php
$POSTurl = 'https://www.primarycare.nhs.uk/publicfn/geocode.ashx';
$fields = array(
'postcode' => urlencode('M41 0UX'),
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $POSTurl );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);



$url = 'https://www.primarycare.nhs.uk/publicfn/catchment.aspx?oc=P91012&h=600&w=800&if=0';
$ch = curl_init();
$result = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: 'Is it possible ... ?' , have your tried ?

Comment: I have, I can send a curl post request to the website with different oc codes and postcode but thats where it ends for me, I have no idea how to  receive the javascript alert.

Comment: Your code returns ``53.4519424438477;-2.3516891002655`` . But you want to display same return in alert?

Comment: Apolgies on the page there is a ajax form where you enter your postcode this send this code back to the page and then issues alert, i dont know how to pass this code back to the page. Please try the link above and enter for example M41 0UX

Comment: I am writing a script for you now. Magic was in source code of nhs site.

Comment: Thank you! @Tauras, I look forward to seeing it! I saw the source code just couldnt think where to start, Ajax = > postcode => Poly code = > return response???

Comment: Response is inside your call using curl. But the validation, to check if coordinates is valid or no is in the source code of nhs. Also, i think they are also using some kind of radius search. Basicly, in the source code, there is a list of coordinates, you can check them with given results and then alert your messages.

Comment: If you want, i can write some kind of quick hack script to make that validation you want.

Comment: Please could you write a php script or anything to help as i'm completely at a loss....Many thanks @Tauras

Comment: Okay, give me some time, since i am at job right now

Comment: no problem, and thank you once again with your help...very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here it is:

the problem, why you were not unable to pick proper response is because all valid coordinates was in source code of NHS. I stripped out unwanted code, and checked coordinates by postcode with existing coordinates from the list. Keep in mind, that if anything will be changed in the list in original source, you will need to update that also.

Also, this code, technically **is not 100% correct** and probably you will spent more time to make it more correct for your needs. As i said in the comment, this will work as little hack.

Just copy/paste into your php file, and refresh the page.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$postcode = 'M41 0UX';
$postcode = urlencode($postcode);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.primarycare.nhs.uk/publicfn/geocode.ashx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "PostCode=".$postcode);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
echo $result;
echo '<input id="checker" type="hidden" value="'.$result.'" />';
?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.primarycare.nhs.uk/Private/js/gpos.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.7&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var point;
var poly1=[{x:53.45801,y: -2.33768},{x:53.46046,y: -2.32996},{x:53.45882,y: -2.32447},{x:53.45637,y: -2.3188},{x:53.45351,y: -2.31709},{x:53.44932,y: -2.31468},{x:53.44523,y: -2.31365},{x:53.44216,y: -2.31279},{x:53.43961,y: -2.31417},{x:53.43858,y: -2.31657},{x:53.4394,y: -2.32155},{x:53.44001,y: -2.32893},{x:53.44145,y: -2.33408},{x:53.44329,y: -2.33751},{x:53.44053,y: -2.33648},{x:53.4395,y: -2.34095},{x:53.43838,y: -2.34352},{x:53.44083,y: -2.34627},{x:53.44022,y: -2.35107},{x:53.43899,y: -2.35193},{x:53.43787,y: -2.35107},{x:53.43797,y: -2.35399},{x:53.43715,y: -2.35622},{x:53.43562,y: -2.3576},{x:53.43592,y: -2.35949},{x:53.43449,y: -2.36103},{x:53.43275,y: -2.36017},{x:53.43153,y: -2.36137},{x:53.43275,y: -2.36343},{x:53.43183,y: -2.36515},{x:53.43347,y: -2.36738},{x:53.4349,y: -2.36704},{x:53.43664,y: -2.36738},{x:53.43736,y: -2.3679},{x:53.43705,y: -2.37167},{x:53.43725,y: -2.37459},{x:53.43592,y: -2.37511},{x:53.43664,y: -2.377},{x:53.43623,y: -2.37974},{x:53.43787,y: -2.38077},{x:53.43858,y: -2.37888},{x:53.4395,y: -2.3782},{x:53.43981,y: -2.38197},{x:53.4392,y: -2.38403},{x:53.43797,y: -2.38352},{x:53.43848,y: -2.38609},{x:53.4395,y: -2.38592},{x:53.44073,y: -2.3842},{x:53.44063,y: -2.38747},{x:53.44001,y: -2.3909},{x:53.43776,y: -2.39193},{x:53.43603,y: -2.39141},{x:53.4348,y: -2.38884},{x:53.43255,y: -2.39038},{x:53.43388,y: -2.39553},{x:53.43459,y: -2.39914},{x:53.43684,y: -2.40051},{x:53.43766,y: -2.40223},{x:53.4394,y: -2.4012},{x:53.44012,y: -2.40429},{x:53.4394,y: -2.40824},{x:53.43868,y: -2.41219},{x:53.44533,y: -2.40807},{x:53.4485,y: -2.40669},{x:53.4529,y: -2.40309},{x:53.45545,y: -2.39965},{x:53.45995,y: -2.39313},{x:53.46363,y: -2.38438},{x:53.46608,y: -2.37614},{x:53.46894,y: -2.3703},{x:53.46588,y: -2.36532},{x:53.46455,y: -2.35931},{x:53.46281,y: -2.35296},{x:53.46158,y: -2.3461},{x:53.45995,y: -2.34198},{x:53.4577,y: -2.33974}];

function isPointInPoly(poly, pt){
for(var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)
((poly[i].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[j].y) || (poly[j].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[i].y))
&& (pt.x < (poly[j].x - poly[i].x) * (pt.y - poly[i].y) / (poly[j].y - poly[i].y) + poly[i].x)
&& (c = !c);
return c;
};

function ispostcodein(postcode) {
var ok = 1;
if (ok == 1) {
var responseText = $('#checker').val();
point = responseText.split(';');
}
var incatch = 0;
if (isPointInPoly(poly1, {x: point[0],y: point[1]})) { incatch = 1 };
if (incatch==0) {  
alert("We're sorry, but your postcode is outside the catchment area for PRIMROSE AVENUE SURGERY.");
}
else {
alert("Your postcode is in the catchment area for PRIMROSE AVENUE SURGERY. You are able to register with this practice.");
}                         
}

ispostcodein('<?= $result; ?>');
</script>
<?php
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: You are a GOD! this worked just as I wanted it too! I amended it slightly as some of the source code changes depending on oc...but I can't thank you enough...thank you so much once again for taking the time to help with this!!!